# Is there a better way to go about this, creating a class to call different functions for a calculator?(Python 3.3)

Tags: python, python-3.3

I am really new at this whole programming thing. The below code works good, I was just wondering if there are other ways to implement this.

Should my init function be that complex or should I call another function with it to can call my other functions?

```
class calculator():

    def __init__(self):
        while True:
            self.ask = str(input("What would you like to calculate? Degrees, Trapezoids, or Circles?"))
            if self.ask == "degrees":
                self.f_to_c_calc()
            elif self.ask == "trapezoid":
                self.calc_trapeziod_area()
            elif self.ask == "circle":
                self.cal_circle()
            else:
                break

    def f_to_c_calc(self):
        temp = int(input("How warm is it out?"))
        f_or_c = str(input("Is it Celsius or Fahrenheit?"))
        if f_or_c == "c" or f_or_c == "C":
            updatedtemp = float(temp * 9 / 5 + 32)
            print (updatedtemp, "°F")
        elif f_or_c == "f" or f_or_c == "F":
            updatedtemp = float((temp - 32) * 5 / 9)
            print (updatedtemp, "°C")

    def calc_trapeziod_area(self):
        height = float(input("What is the height of the trapezoid?"))
        length1 = float(input("What is the length of the top base?"))
        length2 = float(input("What is the length of the bottom base?"))
        formula = float((1 / 2 * (length1 + length2)) * height)
        print ("Your Trapezoids area is:",(formula))

    def cal_circle(self):
        pi = float(245850922 / 78256779)
        rad_or_diam = str(input("Is the number the Diameter or Radius?"))
        if rad_or_diam == "r" or rad_or_diam == "radius":
            radius = float(input("What is the radius of the circle?"))
            area_circ = float(pi * radius ** 2)
            print (area_circ)
        elif rad_or_diam == "d" or rad_or_diam == "diameter":
            diameter = float(input("What is the Diameter of the circle?"))
            area_circ = float(pi * diameter)
            print (area_circ)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    caculate = calculator()
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/  this site might be better to ask these type questions.

Comment: No, you shouldn't put your main code in an `__init__`. There only should be initialization stuff in there. Make a new function called `execute` (or something), and call it just after you create the calculator: `calculate = calculator()` then `calculate.execute()`.

Answer (score 0):

In general, "this works, but are there other ways to do this?" is not a good format for this site.  However, here's a partial answer: classes are for binding state to function, and not for organizing code.  (Opinions differ on this, which is one reason this is not a good question format for this site, but this is mine -- for more info on this theory, see [Stop Writing Classes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0).) By and large, there is no utility to using a class to organize your code this way, because the functionality of your program is procedural.  If you were to break off all of these methods and turn them into functions, you could probably end up with less complex code that does the same thing.

Comment: That was a good amount of information, appreciate it. I am going to simplify it, I also looked up Zen of python and am reading through it also. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome.  Another suggestion: if you find the "if... elif... elif..." system of string comparison tiresome, there is another way to do it using dictionaries that map string keys to functions: http://blog.tplus1.com/blog/2007/06/24/using-dictionaries-rather-than-complex-if-elif-else-clauses/ You'd wrap it in a `try:` block and use `except KeyError:` to handle the `else:` case.

Comment: Ok, so I tried that but it just runs in circles and does not match my dict. So how do I get the try to cycle through the dict and match my variable then execute the code. Right now it just cycles through the dict and executes it all, one at a time very nicely. def run_time():
    ask = str(input("What would you like to calculate? Degrees, Trapezoids, or Circles?"))
    key = {("degrees"): f_to_c_calc(),
           ("trapezoid"): calc_trapeziod_area(),
           ("circle"): cal_circle()
           }
    try:
        key == ask
        raise
    except KeyError:
        print ("You messed up!")

Comment: I did that and it still cycled through the dict, I like how you can call it like this but I guess I am missing some base understanding. I think I have my dict defined wrong. I loaded just the key into my shell and it ran the program right away and did not store it as  a dict.